# "Only me" or "Only I" (is working today)

Tags: questions, pronouns

Which is correct?

> Only **me** is working today?
>   Only **I** is working today?

Which of these should I use? Or neither?

Answer (score 5):

You should use "I", but the verb must agree.

> Only I am working today.

But other expressions are possible and may be prefered:

> I am the only person working today.

Comment: Or you could say *the only person working today is me*, if you want to keep *me* and *is*.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to say. **I'm the only** one working today or I'm working **by myself** today if you're completely alone.

Answer (score 0):

"I is" (does not exist) "is" should be used only in the third person, E.g. She is, He is, They are.

The correct use of I will be: I am, I will, I was...

Answering...
I am the only person working here today.

Comment: Please do not repeat answers on SE sites